# MySQLi OOP Class Select Function Not Working

Tags: php, oop, select, mysqli

I have just created a select function for my database class that I am creating. This is what I have created so far:

```
public function select($columns = array(), $table, $variables = '', $order = '') {
        // Are the required variables empty or equals null?
        if(empty($columns) || empty($table)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Set $order and $variables to false
        if($order == '' || $order == null) {
            $order = false;
        }else if($variables == '' || $variables == null) {
            $variables = false;
        }

        // Check if $columns is an array
        if(!is_array($columns)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Set $fields as an array
        $fields = array();
        // Individualise the array
        foreach($columns as $field) {
            $fields[] = $field;
        }

        // Sepeate all individuals with commas
        $fields = implode(', ', $fields);

        // Finalise the MySQLi query
        if($variables == false && $order == false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table";
        }else if($variables != false && $order == false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table WHERE $variables";
        }else if($variables == false && $order != false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table ORDER BY $order";
        }else if($variables != false && $order != false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table WHERE $variables ORDER BY $order";
        }

        // Prepare the query for executing
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

        // Execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        // Get the results of the query
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        // Set the results to a variable
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }

        // Return the results
        return $results;
    }
```

I have just started learning OOP PHP and prepared statements so I maybe getting a few things wrong.

But the whole thing works, when I used print_r for printing out the results, it was printing the selected results from the database, but for some reason when I use the following, I just get the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: name

This is what I am calling on the index page:

```
$dbc = new dbc();
$query = $dbc->select(array('name', 'setting'), 'options', 'id="1"');

echo $query['name'];
```

I can't figure out why it is doing this? It's returning results from the function and I'm attempting to echo out the results.

Thanks,
Kieron

Comment: what does `var_dump($query)` give you?

Comment: This what I done earlier and it just printed out the correct results from the database: array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Title" ["setting"]=> string(11) "New Website" } }

Comment: Try `echo $query[1]['name'];` You have an array of array and not just an array.

Comment: Nope didn't work it just gave this error: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 But when I changed it to $query[0]['name'] it worked.

Comment: It should be 0 as Rajdeep Paul pointed out. You should probably inspect this @ http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the DB select, you are setting an array of array `$results[]`.

When you get it back you are accessing it as 1 array, it should be:

```
echo $query[0]['name'];
```

Alternatively you can create a new method `select_row` which only returns 1 row at which you can access without array of arrays.

Comment: It should be `echo $query[0]['name'];`

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't I just return $results[0]; or would this cause problems? I have just done it and it works, but I'm just wondering if this would cause issues in the long run?

Comment: @Kieron If you do and the select has more than 1 row to return, you will only get the first row.